# Tag wiki has different text for edit access depending on tag wiki page existance

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

Tag wiki has different text for edit access depending on tag wiki page existence. This happens when user does not have right to edit tag wiki page.

When tag wiki page already exists:

> To edit this wiki, you must have at least 100 upvotes on non-community-wiki answers in this tag (you currently have 3), and at least 2000 reputation.

When tag wiki page does not exist:

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 2000 reputation, provided:
>
> They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or
>
> They have a total score of 100 or more for this tag

The difference is **They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag**. Or are the rules actually different for editing an existing page and for creating a new page?

Also, in the latter case, the page does not tell me how many related votes I already have.

Comment: the "points" part also isn't clear.  on one its stated as "100 upvotes" and on the other it says "total score of 100 or more".  wouldn't 100 upvotes be 1000 points?

Comment: The other issue is that you actually get tag-wiki-edit permission at 1500 rep, not 2000

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the old system was way too confusing, the new system is no longer affected by this issue. All registered users can submit changes to tag wikis.